# How do I get input from a JtextField in one class to an ArrayList in another class. Java

Tags: java, string, arraylist, actionlistener, jtextfield

Ok.  I have two classes. One is my GUI and the other has an ArrayList on it. The GUI is working great and my ActionListeners are all working fine.  My question is - how i take the inputs from the textfields and zap them across into my ArrayList for further processing?

How do I get the values that have been entered into textfeilds in one class into an ArrayList in another class?  I know how to populate the ArrayList. I just don't no how to populate tha ArrayList using information from a textfeild in a different class.

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. What do you mean by "send or call"?

Comment: I have amended my question.

Comment: `String text1 = tf1.getText(); String text2 = tf2.getText(); someOtherObject.zapThemAccross(text1, text2);`?

Answer (score 0):

Your GUI class needs to keep a reference to the class that contains the ArrayList, then in your action-listener you add whatever's in your textfields to your ArrayList via the reference to the class that contains the ArrayList, like so;

```
class GUI
{
   ArrayListContainer alc;

   public GUI(ArrayListContainer alc)
   {
      this.alc = alc.
   }

   public void methodInvokedByActionListener()
   {
      alc.appendToArrayList(myTextField.getText());
   }
}

class ArrayListContainer
{
   ArrayList<String> lst;

   public void appendToArrayList(String s)
   {
      lst.add(s);
   }
}
```

(Obviously there's a lot of code missing here, but you get the gist)

Comment: YES i do. thank you.  i will try this approach first thing in the morning.